# rethinkdb | nested vs chained queries, any difference?

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

is there any difference between chained:

```
r.db('catbox').table("bw_mobile").filter(
    r.row("value")("appVersion")("major").le(2)
).filter(
  r.row("value")("appVersion")("minor").le(2)
).filter(
  r.row("value")("appVersion")("patch").le(10)
)
```

nested:

```
r.db('catbox').table("bw_mobile").filter(
      r.row("value")("appVersion")("major").le(2).and(
        r.row("value")("appVersion")("minor").le(2).and(
          r.row("value")("appVersion")("patch").le(10)
        )
      )
)
```

or lambda functions

```
r.db('catbox').table("bw_mobile").filter(
  r.js("(function (session) { 
        return session.value.appVersion.major < 0 
            || ( session.value.appVersion.major == 0 && session.value.appVersion.minor < 0 )
            || ( session.value.appVersion.major == 0 && session.value.appVersion.minor == 0 && session.value.appVersion.patch < 71 )
        ; 
    })")
)
```

TY!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that the second case (single `filter` with multiple `and` expressions) is the most efficient and the most convenient to use.
I would take the following ideas into account:

`r.filter`, as it's [documented](https://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/filter/), *always* creates a new selection, a stream or an array regardless the results of the predicate function passed to `r.filter`.
I'm not sure how selections are implemented in RethinkDB (I believe they are stream-like), but arrays chaining may be an expensive operation allocating intermediate arrays.
Compare this to `Array.prototype.filter` which creates a new array as its result.
Streams are lazy thus each element is computed (or not) lazily as well, hence making a smaller memory foot-print.
Compare this with iterators/streams and generators in other languages (`Iterator<E>`/`Stream<E>` in Java, `IEnumerator<T>` and `yield return` in .NET/C#,  iterators and generator functions in JavaScript, `yield` in Python, pipes `|` in shell commands. etc) where you can combine iterators/generators.
In any case you have intermediate filters.

A single expression can replace a bunch of chained filter operations.
Note the `r.and` operation in your expression has one very important feature: this is a short-circuit evaluation operation.
If the left-hand operand of the AND operation is `false`, the operation does not even need to evaluate the right-hand expression to get the result that is always `false` then.
You cannot do such a thing with `r.filter`.
Compare this with the SQL WHERE clause that can be specified once per a single query (all false cases can be simply discarded by the `AND` operator).
Also, from a pragmatic perspective, you can create a factory method that can have a convenient name and returns parameterized ReQL expressions, that can even be assigned to constants since ReQL expressions are immutable and safe to re-use:

```js
const maxVersionIs = (major, minor, patch) => r.row("value")("appVersion")("major").le(major)
    .and(r.row("value")("appVersion")("minor").le(minor))
    .and(r.row("value")("appVersion")("patch").le(patch));

const versionPriorToMilestone = maxVersionIs(2, 2, 10);

...

.filter(maxVersionIs(major, minor, patch))

...

.filter(versionPriorToMilestone)
```

ReQL expressions RethinkDB queries are actually expression trees that are much easier to parse and directly convert to execution plan than execute JavaScript scripts.
The official documentation even [recommends](https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/js/) avoid use of `r.js` for better performance.
I guess the cost here is JavaScript runtime setup, isolated script execution and checking for the script timeout.
Additionally, scripts are more error-prone, whereas expression trees can be more or less inspected during compilation time.
But, for the sake of completeness, `r.js` can be more powerful even with those costs, because ReQL is a limited set of operations.
From my personal experience: I had to implement a sort of a permission-checking subsystem based on RethinkDB, and I needed to have a bitwise AND operation in RethinkDB.
Unfortunately, RethinkDB as of 2.3 does not support bitwise operations, so I had to use `r.js`: `r.js('(function (user) { return !!(user.permissions & ${permissions}); })')`.
A future release of RethinkDB will support [bitwise operations](https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/pull/6534), so `r.getField('permissions').bitAnd(permissions))` should work someday in the future faster and combinable with other expressions to fit in a single `filter`.

Answer (score 0):

Because I ran into a similar issue last night and there's not a lot of RethinkDB content here, I'll share my solution.

```js
export interface LooseObjectInterface {
  [key: string]: any;
};

const tldQuery: LooseObjectInterface = await r.table(tldDatabase)
  .orderBy({ index: r.asc("name") }) // alphabetical sort
  .filter((row: any) => {
    return row("collection")
      .contains(suppliedCollection[0])
      .or(row("collection").contains(suppliedCollection[1]))
      .or(row("collection").contains(suppliedCollection[2]))
      .or(row("collection").contains(suppliedCollection[3]))
      // ^ these extra "or"s silently fail, huzzah!
  })
  .pluck("name") // we just want the names
  .run(databaseConnection);
```

In my code, `suppliedCollection` is an array of strings. Each item in my table could have any amount of strings in `suppliedCollection`, from one to four.

Based on these strings in one item's collection, I want to find other items that contain these same strings.

Thankfully, RethinkDB silently fails if `suppliedCollection[n]` is `undefined`.